# Unity CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to install APK to device. Permission denied

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, build

I try to build Unity app to Android and receive next error:

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to install APK to device. 
Please make sure the Android SDK is installed and is properly configured in the Editor. 
See the Console for more details. 
/Users/tedromanus/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb -s "0123456789ABCDEF" install -r "/Users/tedromanus/Workspace/SoftServe/GPSTest/Builds/GPSTest.apk"

stderr[

]
stdout[
[  0%] /data/local/tmp/GPSTest.apk
[  0%] /data/local/tmp/GPSTest.apk
[  0%] /data/local/tmp/GPSTest.apk
[  1%] /data/local/tmp/GPSTest.apk
[  1%] /data/local/tmp/GPSTest.apk
[  1%] /data/local/tmp/GPSTest.apk
[  1%] /data/local/tmp/GPSTest.apk
[  2%] /data/local/tmp/GPSTest.apk
[  2%] /data/local/tmp/GPSTest.apk
[  2%] /data/local/tmp/GPSTest.apk
adb: error: failed to copy '/Users/tedromanus/Workspace/SoftServe/GPSTest/Builds/GPSTest.apk' to '/data/local/tmp/GPSTest.apk': 
Permission denied
]
exit code: 255
```

How can I fix it?
Thanks for response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you own the *tedromanus* user folder? if not, make sure you have admin permission to access that folder.

if you have multiple user accounts on the device, you might make sure that you are on the admin account and if that still doesn't work, deleting any trace of the app off of other user accounts and retrying,

otherwise, I've seen elsewhere that a rooted android device might have this problem.

Comment: There is only one account on my laptop (`tedromanus`). It has all admin privileges.

Comment: But you're right - device is rooted and I never made builds on it before. So problem can be with root. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this for me was I had to add the unity android sdk to the path environment variable